# Create a macro for heading

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs

`LNCS` class requires `3rd-level heading` to be "**Run-in Heading in Bold.** Text follows" at `10 point, bold`

It seems that there is no existing macro for that, so I have written:

```
\newcommand{\headingthree}[1]{\noindent\textbf{#1}}
```

I also use `\paragraph`, I realize that `\paragraph` automatically adds a line above the text, but `\headingthree` doesn't.

Does anyone know how to make my `\headingthree` automatically add space above the text as a `\paragraph` does?

PS: the 3rd-level heading:
[image]

Comment: Would redefining one of the existing sectional commands be an option for you?

Comment: I don't know, it seems that LaTeX does some mysterious thing for a sectional command, adjust the position smartly... I just want to realize something close to `3rd-level heading` the doc requires and be really a sectional command...

Comment: Please see my answer, and let me know if that is, more or less, what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of the `titlesec` package you can redefine one of the existing sectional unit commands to produce the desired layout; in the following example I redefined `\subsubsection` to have a run-in title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Test subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Apparently the question has been answered; however, looking at the image that appears in the question, the following re-definitions of `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph` will produce sectioning units with the given specifications for the first four levels shown, in a document with the default `10pt` size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{}[.]
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}{}{0em}{}[.]

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}% don't include subsubsections in ToC

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Test subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\lipsum[2]
\paragraph{Test paragraph}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see you can redefine `\subsubsection`, do you mind telling me directly what to do to make the title `10 point, bold` as the figure requires?

Comment: @SoftTimur I dont undestand your comment; the code as it is will produce the title in 10pt and boldfaced.

Comment: @SoftTimur: do you want to hard-code the 10pt size for the title?

Answer (score 4):

The class provides `\subsubsection` that does exactly what you need:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter              % start of the contributions

\title{A title}
\author{A. N. Thor}
%
\institute{Nowhere University, Princeton NJ 08544, USA,\\
\email{thor@nowhere.edu}}

\maketitle              % typeset the title of the contribution

\begin{abstract}
A very short  abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\lipsum[2]

\paragraph{Ghi}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]